# compiler error while processing libcostmap_2d.so

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have been working with navigation stack for a while without any problem but now, i am facing compiler error written below

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so', needed by '/home/serhatsony/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libcostmap_2d.so'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:20521: recipe for target 'navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeFiles/costmap_2d.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeFiles/costmap_2d.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....


make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so', needed by '/home/serhatsony/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libcostmap_2d.so'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:20521: recipe for target 'navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeFiles/costmap_2d.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeFiles/costmap_2d.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I guess, the problem is related to 'some update situtation'. I had executed these two commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

any relationship? Or how can i solve this problem?
Thank you!
UBUNTU 16.04 -
Kinetic (I have uploaded directly navigation stack with the branch of kinetic-devel )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367010/compiler-error-while-processing-libcostmap_2d.so/) by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2020-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on 2020-12-08**:
Hello Jarvis again, after doing "apt-get update/upgrade", i am still facing the same problem. I saw the updates on Kinetic Kame as you mentioned in your comment and even upgraded my system too. But the problem keeps resisting. What should i do? Can you explain the solution with a little bit of explanation please? Or what might be the problem? I am new in the Ros in fact.

Thank you!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-12-08**:
@serhat please do not post answers that are not actually answers. I've moved your answer into a question comment. First, I'd figure out what versions of VTK, libproj, and pcl you have installed (`dpkg -l |grep "vtk\|libproj\|pcl"`). Ensure you have `libproj-dev` installed, ensure you're on the `6.2.0+dfsg1-10ubuntu0.1` versions of VTK (e.g. `libvtk6-dev`), and on the ROS PCL packages from December 3 (e.g. 1.4.4-0xenial-20201203-014302+0000 for `ros-kinetic-perception-pcl`). If yes to all of those, did you try cleaning your workspace before building? Can you confirm `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so` doesn't exist which is what the error in your question indicates is the problem (it should be installed by `libproj-dev` package)?

**Comment by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on 2020-12-09**:
Hi Jarvis, I installed libproj-dev. And this solved my problem. I don't get any error while compiling anymore. Thank you for your explanations and patience. Regards.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-12-09**:
Glad that worked! The only thing that surprises me a bit is that it wasn't already installed. The latest version  of `libvtk6-dev` (6.2.0+dfsg1-10ubuntu0.1) has a Deb dependency on `libproj-dev`. Meaning, if your apt upgrade had worked according to my answer you should have had `libproj-dev` installed automatically. I'm guessing that even though you've fixed your issue, you might still have different package versions installed. For example, if you still had the version of `libvtk6-dev` from OSRF's repositories (6.2.0+dfsg1-10build1+debian11.1+osrf1) then you wouldn't get `libproj-dev` installed automatically.

**Comment by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on 2020-12-11**:
Hi Jarvis, the problem might be my internet connection. I work in a university whose wifi is kind of under control(firewall or something like that). I see some errors occasionally while downloading somethings from internet such as "Failed to fetch". In these kind of situations, I open my internet to download properly. But I forget sometimes... and go on with broken downloaded packages or programs. This is my opinion how the some files are overlooked.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-12-11**:
Sounds like a reasonable theory. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even though the error is slightly different, this is the same error as mentioned in [this recent question](https://answers.ros.org/question/366812/ubuntu-1604-kinetic-update-no-rule-to-make-target-libvtkproj/). You are right,  a change was pushed to Ubuntu and OSRF apt repositories that introduced this issue. Here are a few related bug reports:

- https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/318
- https://github.com/tfoote/vtk6-release/issues/1
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vtk6/+bug/1573234

Current recommended fix is to pin your apt repos to prefer the versions of VTK packages on OSRF's repositories over the ones on Ubuntu's repositories (as mentioned in [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/366812/ubuntu-1604-kinetic-update-no-rule-to-make-target-libvtkproj/?answer=366913#post-id-366913)). To do this, create a file called `/etc/apt/preferences.d/ros-pin` with the following content

```
Package: *
Pin: origin packages.ros.org
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

Then `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` can be used to switch you to the OSRF versions. Also note, that you may need to manually install `libproj-dev`. Hopefully this is a temporary issue that is fixed soon.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned on [this ROS discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-kinetic-kame-2020-12-07/17786) thread, an update to the ROS Kinetic packages that depend on VTK was just released to the package repositories. Users should be able to unpin any pinned packages (e.g. delete file created above), and then run `apt-get` update/upgrade to install the latest packages, and this error should disappear.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [serhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/64454/serhat/) on 2020-12-05**:
Thank you very much Jarvis. I'll take a look similar bugs and try to do the steps you said.
I appreciate for the feedback!